# Using regex to match two specific characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings like:

```
1,-102a
1,123-f
1943dsa
-da238,
-,dwjqi92
```

How can I make a Regex expression in Python that matches as long as the string contains the characters `,` AND `-` regardless of the order or the pattern in which they appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following regex alternation:

```regex
,.*-|-.*,
```

Sample script:

```py
inp = ['1,-102a', '1,123-f', '1943dsa', '-da238,', '-,dwjqi92']
output = [x for x in inp if re.search(r',.*-|-.*,', x)]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['1,-102a', '1,123-f', '-da238,', '-,dwjqi92']
```